# Python3 super not initializing __init__ attributes

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, super

I have the following code snippet:

```
class BaseUserAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        accountRefNo = "RefHDFC001"
        FIType = "DEPOSIT"
        pan = "AFF34964FFF"
        mobile = "9822289017"
        email = "manoja@cookiejar.co.in"
        aadhar = "5555530495555"


class TestUserSavingsAccount(BaseUserAccount):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        accountNo = "HDFC111111111111"
        accountTypeEnum = "SAVINGS"

    def test_create_account(self):
        request_body = """\
            <UserAccountInfo>
                <UserAccount accountRefNo="{}" accountNo="{}"
                accountTypeEnum="{}" FIType="{}">
                    <Identifiers pan="{}" mobile="{}" email="{}" aadhar="{}"></Identifiers>
                </UserAccount>
            </UserAccountInfo>
        """.format(self.accountRefNo, self.accountNo, self.accountTypeEnum,
                self.FIType, self.pan, self.mobile, self.email, self.aadhar)
```

If I run this code in the interactive shell:

```
>>> t = TestUserSavingsAccount()
>>> t.accountRefNo
AttributeError: 'TestUserSavingsAccount' object has no attribute 'accountRefNo'
>>> t.accountNo
AttributeError: 'TestUserSavingsAccount' object has no attribute 'accountNo'
```

Seeing the above behavior, it seems like the `super` is neither setting up values from the base class and neither the attributes of the child (`accountNo`, `accountTypeEnum`) are being set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote only assign those values to local variables. You need to initialize attributes of the `self` object instead:

```
class BaseUserAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accountRefNo = "RefHDFC001"
        self.FIType = "DEPOSIT"
        self.pan = "AFF34964FFF"
        self.mobile = "9822289017"
        self.email = "manoja@cookiejar.co.in"
        self.aadhar = "5555530495555"


class TestUserSavingsAccount(BaseUserAccount):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.accountNo = "HDFC111111111111"
        self.accountTypeEnum = "SAVINGS"
```